# Prevent the CLR from freeing memory of a marshalled double char pointer?

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

I am building a Visual Studio 2022 extension in C# and am currently playing around with the VS API. I am trying to call [`IVsObjectList2.GetText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsobjectlist2.gettext?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-ivsobjectlist2-gettext(system-uint32-microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-vstreetextoptions-system-string@)), which is a COM interface. However, VS is crashing while attempting to do so. I suspect that the marshalling definition is wrong in the VS API.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsobjectlist2.gettext?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-ivsobjectlist2-gettext(system-uint32-microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-vstreetextoptions-system-string@)) states that the 3rd argument to `GetText()` (the string) should **NOT** be freed by the caller. I.e. the native interface is defined as

```
HRESULT IVsObjectList2::GetText(  
   [in] ULONG Index,   
   [in] VSTREETEXTOPTIONS tto,   
   [out] const WCHAR **ppszText  
);
```

and `ppszText` must not be freed by the caller of `GetText()`. However, in the decompilation of the C# code I can see that `GetText()` is defined as

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig | MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
int GetText(
  [In][ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.ULONG")] uint index,
  [In][ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSTREETEXTOPTIONS")] VSTREETEXTOPTIONS tto,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszText);
```

From what I understand, the [default marshalling behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-behavior#unmanaged-signature) is causing the CLR to free the string argument `ppszText` automatically. Is my understanding correct?

If I am correct, since this is then at odds with the API definition, can I somehow hack around the issue? I mean can I somehow correct the marshalling definition of `GetText()` in my own code? (I think the third argument [should be an `IntPtr` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/x3txb6xc(v=vs.100))?) For example, if this were C++, I would maybe do a "reinterpret_cast" of `IVsObjectList2` to an own definition that is then correct; is something like this possible in C#?

Calling C# code:

```
IVsObjectManager2 objectManager2 = MyExtensionPackage.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsObjectManager)) as IVsObjectManager2;
if (objectManager2.FindLibrary(new Guid(BrowseLibraryGuids80.VC), out IVsLibrary2 lib) == VSConstants.S_OK) {
  var criteria = new VSOBSEARCHCRITERIA2();
  if (lib.GetList2(
        (uint)_LIB_LISTTYPE.LLT_CLASSES, 
        (uint)_LIB_LISTFLAGS.LLF_DONTUPDATELIST, 
        new[] { criteria }, 
        out IVsObjectList2 list) == VSConstants.S_OK
      && list != null) {
    if (list.GetItemCount(out uint count) == VSConstants.S_OK && count > 0) {
      for (uint idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) {
        // The following crashes eventually.
        list.GetText(idx, VSTREETEXTOPTIONS.TTO_PREFIX, out string prefix);
        // Use "prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `list.GetText()` call doesn't crash immediately, but eventually does so because of some heap corruption with the following callstack:

```
ntdll.dll!RtlpBreakPointHeap()
ntdll.dll!RtlpValidateHeapEntry()
ntdll.dll!RtlValidateHeap()
AcLayers.dll!NS_FaultTolerantHeap::APIHook_RtlFreeHeap(void *,unsigned long,void *)
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffe31eb071f()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop.ni.dll!00007ffe2d8bfc53()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop.ni.dll!00007ffe2d8bfbe7()
[Managed to Native Transition]
My own code in C#, line with GetText()
```

Comment: Your documentation link doesn't appear to say that the string should not be freed by the caller.

Comment: Quote from docs "If you are implementing the IVsObjectList2 interface in managed code and you need to have the string disposed by the caller, implement the IVsCoTaskMemFreeMyStrings interface on the IVsObjectList2 interface." and "Managed code should implement the IVsCoTaskMemFreeMyStrings interface on those specific interfaces to indicate that the string really should be freed by the caller; otherwise, the caller does not free the string." So if you implement that marker interface then it knwos you are going to free the string.

Comment: The point is that I am NOT implementing the interface. I am USING the interface. So the sentence "Implementers must allocate this string and keep the pointer valid as per the remarks below." implies that callers should not free the string, because the implementation is allowed to reuse it. Of course, an implementation is also allowed to free it: manually, or by implementing `IVsCoTaskMemFreeMyStrings`. But this only works if the caller is not already freeing it. Otherwise we get a double free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean can I somehow correct the marshalling definition of GetText() in my own code?

One thing you can generally do in .NET is you can define your own copy of IVsObjectList2 interface with the same GUID attribute, and same method ordering, and then cast the object to your interface. That would then allow you to redefine the GetText method with a more appropriate signature. Unfortunately this can be a pain, since you need to be careful to do things like keep the interface members in the same order as the underlying IDL.

Comment: Thanks, this hack works. No more crashes after changing the string argument to `IntPtr`. So I accepted the answer. But: You don't happen to know about some other workaround where I don't have to duplicate the whole `IVsObjectList2` interface, and fiddle only with the `GetText()` function? Maybe one could use some reflection trick?

Comment: The only other trick that comes to mind is the CLR is matching the vtable method entries by the order of the methods in the interface, so if you only need just one you can just declare all the other methods with some stub "void Unused1()" "void Unused2()" so that way you only have to declare the one you care about. But for a big interface like that it's not much solace...